# Does getting perks above 600 do anything?

Tags: for-honor

I've been playing For Honor and I noticed that you can get your perks above 600 limit. I assumed this would make the perk stronger but when I went into Perk Definitions it only said they needed to be at 600 to be activated. So does getting a perk higher than 600 change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's anything below 600, it isn't activated = does literally nothing. If it's above 600, it is activated = does what its description says. No other possibilities

Comment: You should aim to be as little as possible over the 600 points in order to optimise your equipment.